# Conditionally select value from one of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a questionnaire application, where a user will submit answers. Some of the questions are text based and some have fixed options.

The values are saved to the `tAnswers` table as either the entered text value, or the `Id` of the selected option. There is a `QuestionTypeId` column which defines if the answer is a reference to `tOptions.Id`.

I want to select the answers, returning the entered value or the value related to the selected Id.

For example;

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @tSubmissions TABLE (Id INT)
DECLARE @tSubmissionQuestions TABLE (SubmissionId INT, QuestionId INT)
DECLARE @tQuestions TABLE (Id INT, QuestionText NVARCHAR(MAX), ColName NVARCHAR(MAX), QuestionTypeId INT)
DECLARE @tOptions TABLE (Id INT, OptionValue NVARCHAR(MAX), OptionGroupId INT)
DECLARE @tAnswers TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), SubmissionId INT, QuestionId INT, AnswerValue NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @tQuestions VALUES (1, 'What is your name?', 'Name', 1)
INSERT INTO @tQuestions VALUES (2, 'What is your age?', 'Age', 1)
INSERT INTO @tQuestions VALUES (3, 'What is your gender?', 'Gender', 2)
INSERT INTO @tQuestions VALUES (4, 'What is your favourite colour?', 'Colour', 2)

-- Answers for question 3 - gender
INSERT INTO @tOptions VALUES (1, 'Male', 1)
INSERT INTO @tOptions VALUES (2, 'Female', 1)

-- answers for question 4 - colour
INSERT INTO @tOptions VALUES (3, 'Blue', 2)
INSERT INTO @tOptions VALUES (4, 'Green', 2)
INSERT INTO @tOptions VALUES (5, 'Red', 2)
INSERT INTO @tOptions VALUES (6, 'Yellow', 2)

INSERT INTO @tSubmissions VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @tSubmissions VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @tSubmissions VALUES (3)

INSERT INTO @tSubmissionQuestions VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO @tSubmissionQuestions VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO @tSubmissionQuestions VALUES (1, 3)
INSERT INTO @tSubmissionQuestions VALUES (1, 4)
INSERT INTO @tSubmissionQuestions VALUES (2, 1)
INSERT INTO @tSubmissionQuestions VALUES (2, 2)
INSERT INTO @tSubmissionQuestions VALUES (2, 3)
INSERT INTO @tSubmissionQuestions VALUES (2, 4)
INSERT INTO @tSubmissionQuestions VALUES (3, 1)
INSERT INTO @tSubmissionQuestions VALUES (3, 2)
INSERT INTO @tSubmissionQuestions VALUES (3, 3)
INSERT INTO @tSubmissionQuestions VALUES (3, 4)

-- form submissions
INSERT INTO @tAnswers (SubmissionId, QuestionId, AnswerValue) VALUES (1, 1, 'Tony Stark')
INSERT INTO @tAnswers (SubmissionId, QuestionId, AnswerValue) VALUES (1, 2, '39')
INSERT INTO @tAnswers (SubmissionId, QuestionId, AnswerValue) VALUES (1, 3, '1') -- reference to @tOptions
INSERT INTO @tAnswers (SubmissionId, QuestionId, AnswerValue) VALUES (1, 4, '5') -- reference to @tOptions

INSERT INTO @tAnswers (SubmissionId, QuestionId, AnswerValue) VALUES (2, 1, 'Pepper Potts')
INSERT INTO @tAnswers (SubmissionId, QuestionId, AnswerValue) VALUES (2, 2, '38')
INSERT INTO @tAnswers (SubmissionId, QuestionId, AnswerValue) VALUES (2, 3, '2') -- reference to @tOptions
INSERT INTO @tAnswers (SubmissionId, QuestionId, AnswerValue) VALUES (2, 4, '6') -- reference to @tOptions

INSERT INTO @tAnswers (SubmissionId, QuestionId, AnswerValue) VALUES (3, 1, 'James Rhodes')
INSERT INTO @tAnswers (SubmissionId, QuestionId, AnswerValue) VALUES (3, 2, '41') -- has choosen to not answer question 3
INSERT INTO @tAnswers (SubmissionId, QuestionId, AnswerValue) VALUES (3, 4, '3') -- reference to @tOptions

SELECT 
    s.Id as SubmissionId, q.Id as QuestionId, a.AnswerValue
FROM 
    @tSubmissions s
INNER JOIN @tSubmissionQuestions sq
    ON sq.SubmissionId = s.Id
INNER JOIN @tQuestions q
    ON q.Id = sq.QuestionId
LEFT JOIN @tAnswers a
    ON a.QuestionId = q.Id
    AND a.SubmissionId = s.Id
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cda09f210b5a38e0a4f0c615f10c85a2)

This returns;

```
SubmissionId | QuestionId | AnswerValue
=============|============|===============
1            | 1          |  Tony Stark
1            | 2          |  39
1            | 3          |  1     <-- this is the Id of the selected option
1            | 4          |  5     <-- this is the Id of the selected option
2            | 1          |  Pepper Potts
2            | 2          |  38
2            | 3          |  2     <-- this is the Id of the selected option
2            | 4          |  6     <-- this is the Id of the selected option
3            | 1          |  James Rhodes
3            | 2          |  41
3            | 3          |  NULL  <-- the option was not selected
3            | 4          |  3     <-- this is the Id of the option
```

Instead I would like;

```
SubmissionId | QuestionId | AnswerValue
=============|============|===============
1            | 1          |  Tony Stark
1            | 2          |  39
1            | 3          |  Male    <-- this is the value of the selected option
1            | 4          |  Red     <-- this is the value of the selected option
2            | 1          |  Pepper Potts
2            | 2          |  38
2            | 3          |  Female  <-- this is the value of the selected option
2            | 4          |  Yellow  <-- this is the value of the selected option
3            | 1          |  James Rhodes
3            | 2          |  41
3            | 3          |  NULL    <-- the option was not selected
3            | 4          |  Blue    <-- this is the value of the selected option
```

How do I conditionally pull values from the `tOptions` table?

Comment: Are you storing integer IDs in a text field? How do you determine that text "39" in the second row is a free-text answer, but text "1" in the third row has to be interpreted as an integer ID?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov yes Id's are also stored in the text column. There is a `QuestionTypeId` column which defines the answer is a reference to `tOptions.Id`. I'll make this more obvious in the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for:
Another `LEFT JOIN` on tOptions to select the values, in case of `QuestionTypeId = 2` 
I just added the `ISNUMERIC` to avoid conversion errors.

```
SELECT 
    s.Id as SubmissionId, 
    q.Id as QuestionId, 
    COALESCE(t.OptionValue,a.AnswerValue) AS AnswerValue
FROM 
    @tSubmissions s
INNER JOIN @tSubmissionQuestions sq
    ON sq.SubmissionId = s.Id
INNER JOIN @tQuestions q
    ON q.Id = sq.QuestionId
LEFT JOIN @tAnswers a
    ON a.QuestionId = q.Id
    AND a.SubmissionId = s.Id
LEFT JOIN @tOptions t
        ON q.QuestionTypeId = 2
       AND ISNUMERIC(a.AnswerValue) = 1
       AND a.AnswerValue = t.Id
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
SELECT 
    s.Id as SubmissionId, q.Id as QuestionId,
    CASE WHEN q.QuestionTypeId = 1 THEN 
    a.AnswerValue
    ELSE 
    ISNULL((SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),OptionValue) FROM @tOptions o WHERE o.Id = a.AnswerValue),a.AnswerValue)
    END  AS AnswerValue
FROM 
    @tSubmissions s
INNER JOIN @tSubmissionQuestions sq
    ON sq.SubmissionId = s.Id
INNER JOIN @tQuestions q
    ON q.Id = sq.QuestionId
LEFT JOIN @tAnswers a
    ON a.QuestionId = q.Id
    AND a.SubmissionId = s.Id
ORDER BY s.Id ASC
```

Comment: You have edited that's fine. but i don't know your structure.

Comment: I added the `QuestionTypeId` into the condition - it is safer than just checking if the value contains numerics.

Answer (score 2):

I would make two columns in the `Answers` table. One that you have `AnswerValue NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL` and another one `AnswerOptionID int NULL`. It would make joining way more efficient and it would eliminate problems when engine tries to convert text "Tony Stark" into integer.

But, given the schema as is, here is one variant.
I added `LEFT JOIN` to the `@tOptions` table. Note, that I'm converting integer IDs into text, not other way around.

```
SELECT 
    s.Id as SubmissionId, q.Id as QuestionId
    -- , a.AnswerValue, Options.OptionValue
    ,CASE WHEN q.QuestionTypeId = 2 
        THEN Options.OptionValue 
        ELSE a.AnswerValue 
    END AS AnswerText
FROM 
    @tSubmissions s
    INNER JOIN @tSubmissionQuestions sq ON sq.SubmissionId = s.Id
    INNER JOIN @tQuestions q ON q.Id = sq.QuestionId
    LEFT JOIN @tAnswers a
        ON  a.QuestionId = q.Id
        AND a.SubmissionId = s.Id
    LEFT JOIN @tOptions AS Options
        ON  q.QuestionTypeId = 2
        AND a.AnswerValue = CAST(Options.Id AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
;
```

Comment: Great suggestion, but unfortunately I don't have the option of changing the DB schema.